# UDP broadcasting for LAN computer discovery & server setup

Tags: c++, c, udp, broadcast

I'm working on a small, networked game prototype which will be played on LANs using UDP.  For the discovery of other computers on the network, I've been investigating broadcasting.  However, I'm still unsure about a few details regarding UDP socket setup/usage (networking newbie).  I found a good library to use after the game is started, but at first, all computers running the game must be discovered and one has to be chosen as a server.  So my questions are the following:

- Can a single UDP socket be used to listen for and send broadcasts?  I'm pretty sure the answer to this is yes, but I wanted to verify it.
- When using UDP, do you actually have to use `bind()`?  As far as I understand, `connect()` is not required, nor is `send()/recv()`, since they are for TCP (`sendto()/recvfrom()` being the replacements).

Comment: This is a well-thought out question, but it contains multiple questions and probably would be better served as separate questions.

Comment: @0A0D Good point, I wasn't sure if I should split it since they were somewhat related.  I'll leave the UDP ones together and pull out the last two as separate questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, you can send broadcasts, send unicasts and receive packets (either broadcast or unicast) all from a single socket.  This is VERY useful for making "reply to sender" work.
2. Not every socket needs to use bind.  If you don't, a port will be chosen for you automatically.  But someone has to bind a pre-shared port number in order for the first packet (possibly a broadcast) to be properly delivered.  The first packet contains the source port and IP address; reply packets can just use this.
3. Binding both ends to fixed port numbers does however make firewall configuration simpler.
4. `setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST)`, otherwise you'll get errors trying to send broadcast packets.

Comment: Very clear answer, especially the bit about binding--it makes a lot more sense to me now.  Thank you!